# Fscanf, Strings, and Arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I have a programming assignment. The code is laid out for us, we just have to fill it in. Its been a while since i've touched arrays so i need some help.

The program is declaring a char array. It is using fscanf to get strings from a file. The file contains 3 lines of text with two strings separated by a space in each line. So it would look like "12345 abcd".

They have this going in a loop. Questions:

1) is each string stored in separate values of the array ex: array[0] = "12345" and array[1] = "abcd". Its not in this format, right? : array[16] = {1,2,3,4,5, ,a,b,c,d}. The fscan is in a loop. format: (fscanf(in, %s, array)

2) When fscanf is called, does it process 12345 as a separate string (since there is a space after the five) or does it process "12345 abcd" as one string in a file and return it.

3) Lets say i've used fscanf to scan in 12345 and store it in (array[0]). Then i use fscanf in another instance. Will it store the next string "abcd" in array[1]

Thanks

Comment: Please don't attempt to describe code - that's not precise enough. Show the code, and point out exactly what you don't understand, and show your attempt at solving the problem and explain what doesn't work with it.

Comment: Sorry, im new to this., Also i'm not allowed to post code, according to University rules

Comment: Without code any help is not possible. To clear your concept of fscanf please refer to : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your question doesn't show any code and it makes it really hard to answer. I can explain a really easy example and hope it will help you.

Suppose you have a file "file.txt" with only one line of text with two strings separated by a space. The text is: "abcd 12345". You can run following code to read both strings from the file and store them separately in two char arrays.

```
FILE* file;
fopen_s(&file, "file.txt", "r");
char str1[10];
char str2[10];
fscanf(file, "%s %s", str1, str2);
```

To answer your question 1) first array will look like this:

```
str1[0] = 'a'
str1[1] = 'b'
str1[2] = 'c'
str1[3] = 'd'
str1[4] = '\0'
```

You don't really care about the rest since these are null-terminated arrays. Second array:

```
str2[0] = '1'
str2[1] = '2'
str2[2] = '3'
str2[3] = '4'
str2[4] = '5'
str2[5] = '\0'
```

This is how your program most likely works. However it is possible to store whole line in one array and this is the reason why we need to see whole code. Also you are a bit confused by char arrays. I recommend you to go through some documentation first: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: This explained it completely. Thank you... and yea i was a little confused about char arrays. It was the way they had it coded. I get it now. thanks